# Read sub directory of location with 2 php scripts

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have nginx config that i need to read 2 php locations. The first one is based app on codeigniter and second is simple php script with custom paths.

The real paths are :
`/var/www/html/code - codeigniter /var/www/html/php/app - small php script with index.php`

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       listen [::]:443 ssl;

        client_max_body_size 20M;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        root /var/www/html/code;
        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        }
#codeigniter

        location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

#simple php application

               location ^~ /php {
                index index.php;
                alias /var/www/html/php/app;
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string ;
      location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                include        fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

        }

}
```

But when i visit https://example.com/php/some_sub_directory

I get redirected to https://example.com/ (my codeigniter main script which i'm serving on / )

Any ideas?

I have been trying different configs, but this is the the most suitable for me

Comment: After making changes did you `reload or restart Nginx'?

Comment: The second `try_files` statement redirects to `/index.php?$query_string` which is the URL for the codeigniter script. You should use `/php/index.php?$query_string`

Answer (score 0):

`$uri` with `/php/some_sub_directory` will match the `location ^~ /php`, then it will use the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string ;` which will do a internal redirect to `/index.php?$query_string`.

Then the redirect `/index.php?$query_string` will match the `location ~ \.php$` which is your codeigniter.

If you want to match your small php script, set the try_files with `try_files $uri $uri/ /php/index.php?$query_string ;`

Here is the workable config segment demo:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

#simple php application
location ^~ /php {
    index index.php;
    alias /var/www/html/php/app;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /php/index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 200 simplephp;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 200 codephp;
}
```

```
$ curl  -Ss server.test/php/some_sub_directory
simplephp
```